# Order DataTables by invisible data column using columns.orderData

Tags: datatables

For my question I have prepared [a simple test case at JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/xirimi/4/edit?js,output).

In a word game I am trying to display the 20 longest words played by a player.

I deliver the data from PostgreSQL to DataTables jQuery plugin in JSON format. It is already sorted by word length and by the date when words were played.

This order is stored as numeric value (1, 2, 3, ...) in the `row` property of each JSON object:

```
var dataSet = [
    {"row":4,"gid":1,"created":"25.02.2017 14:07","finished":null,"player1":2,"player2":1,"score1":30,"score2":52,"female1":0,"female2":0,"given1":"Abcde3","given2":"Ghijk4","photo1":null,"photo2":null,"place1":null,"place2":null,"word":"ZZ","score":11},
    {"row":2,"gid":1,"created":"25.02.2017 14:07","finished":null,"player1":2,"player2":1,"score1":30,"score2":52,"female1":0,"female2":0,"given1":"Abcde3","given2":"Ghijk4","photo1":null,"photo2":null,"place1":null,"place2":null,"word":"BBBBB","score":6},
    {"row":3,"gid":1,"created":"25.02.2017 14:07","finished":null,"player1":2,"player2":1,"score1":30,"score2":52,"female1":0,"female2":0,"given1":"Abcde3","given2":"Ghijk4","photo1":null,"photo2":null,"place1":null,"place2":null,"word":"ABC","score":7},
    {"row":1,"gid":1,"created":"25.02.2017 14:07","finished":null,"player1":2,"player2":1,"score1":30,"score2":52,"female1":0,"female2":0,"given1":"Abcde3","given2":"Ghijk4","photo1":null,"photo2":null,"place1":null,"place2":null,"word":"XYZXYZXYZ","score":6}
];
```

Here is my JavaScript code, where I try to sort the column `word` (column 2) by the invisible column `row` (column 0):

```
function renderGid(data, type, row, meta) {
    return (type === 'display' ? '<IMG SRC="https://datatables.net/examples/resources/details_open.png"> #' + data : data);
}

function renderGame(data) {
    return 'Details for game #' + data.gid;
}

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var longestTable = $('#longest').DataTable({
        data: dataSet,
        order: [[2, 'desc']],
        columns: [
            { data: 'row',   orderable: false, visible: false },
            { data: 'gid',   orderable: false, visible: true, className: 'details-control', render: renderGid },
            { data: 'word',  orderable: true,  visible: true, orderData: 0 /* order by invisible column 0 */ },
            { data: 'score', orderable: false, visible: true }
        ]
    });

    $('#longest tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var img = $(this).find('img');
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = longestTable.row(tr);

        if (row.child.isShown()) {
            row.child.hide();
            img.attr('src', 'https://datatables.net/examples/resources/details_open.png');
        } else {
            row.child( renderGame(row.data()) ).show();
            img.attr('src', 'https://datatables.net/examples/resources/details_close.png');
        }
    });
});
```

However this does not work - the displayed words order is **ZZ, BBBB, ABC, XYZXYZXYZ** (seemingly unsorted) - while it should be **XYZXYZXYZ, BBBB, ABC, ZZ** (sorted by `row` descending):

[image: jsbin screenshot]

Why does not sorting work even though I have specified [columns.orderData: 0](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.orderData)?

And why can't I change ordering by clicking the greyed out arrows (shown by the red arrow in the above screenshot)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this seems to be [an old bug](https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/22462/sorting-breaks-when-trying-to-use-columns-orderdata-with-order) in dataTables jQuery plugin: the integer argument is not accepted.

I have to change it to an array with the single value:

```
{ data: 'word',  orderable: true,  visible: true, orderData: [0] },
```

and then it works:

[image: jsbin screenshot]

Comment: It seems to work without array when the orderData column number is bigger than 0. But when 0 it needs the array [0]